# C: code does not work without a separate function. Why?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, methods

I'm basically creating a small method/function that cuts a string if its length is longer than the input new_line. However, I have two different version of this.

The first code calculates the length of the string and shortens it all under the same method/function.

The second code has separate functions for both length calculation and trimming the string.

The first code does not work (it does not trim the string) while the second one does work. I don't know why though. 
Thanks

The code that does not work

```
void shorten(char *s, int new_len){
    int len = 0;
    while(*s){
        len++;
        s++;
    }
    while( len > new_len){
        s[len - 1] = '\0';
        s--;
        len--;
    }
}
```

The code that works

```
int length(char *s){ // count length of string
    int len = 0;
    while(*s){
        len++;
        s++;
    }
    return len;
}

void shorten(char *s, int new_len) {
    int len = length(s);
    while( len > new_len){
        s[len - 1] = '\0';
        s--; // move to previous char
        len--; // decrease length
    }
}
```

Comment: `s` has been incremented in your first one... on your second `s` is only a copy so its value didn't change. do `while (s[len]) { len++; }` also I doubt that your second function work better with `s--`

Comment: Why decrease the size in a loop? You may use `s[new_len - 1] = '\0'; len = new_len;` if `len > new_len`.

Comment: why do you reinvent `strlen`?

Comment: You'd need something like `while( len > new_len) { *s = 0; --len; --s; }`, or just make a copy of s before you change it.

Comment: @phuclv It's for an assignment. Can't use string.h

Comment: @Stargateur "has been incremented in your first one..." I initally suspected that but what difference would it make if s is always being called on s[len - 1] ? Wouldn't that just reset the value of s to the last position of the string? Thanks

Comment: @FsimulatorX pointer arithmetic s++, make it avance, so at the end s is at the end of the string, take "stackoverflow", s point to the end the null byte `\0`, let's say `s` was 100 so at the end `s` is `112` now with `s[12 - 1]` you do `112 + 12 - 1 => 123` this is a out of bound.

Comment: you should also learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It'll help you recognize the problem much faster

Answer (score 2):

You are altering the function argument by doing `s++;`, which after the first loop is no longer pointing to the start of the string.
Perhaps you wanted to do this:

```
void shorten(char *s, int new_len){
    int len = 0;
    while(*s){
        len++;
        s++;
    }
    while( len > new_len){
        s--;
        len--;
        *s = '\0';
    }
}
```

Also, it is advisable to use `size_t` for all the size/length/index related operation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is **not** increment the `s` pointer when calculating the length. Also, you can avoid the while loop to reset the length by just setting `s[new_len] = '\0'` if `len > new_len`.

Also, since `strlen()` returns length of type `size_t`, it is advisable to use `size_t` for storing length of the char string (it could eliminate any warnings related to comparison between signed and unsigned values).

```
void shorten(char *s, size_t new_len) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (s[len] != '\0') {
        len++;
    }
    /*while ( len > new_len) {
        s[len - 1] = '\0';
        len--;
    }*/
    if (len > new_len) {
        s[new_len] = '\0';
        len = new_len;
    }
}
```